# c++ IDE which provides separate input/output terminals

Tags: c++, ide

I want an IDE where I can have separate window for input and output. Also it would be great if I could specify all inputs pre compilation. Basically I want an IDE with I/O system exactly like on this website https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++

Comment: Which operating system, what is your price range. Why not use the mentioned system?

Comment: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft, can compile for gcc-7, python, java, and many more...